# Spring redirectAttributes not transferred

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i want to pass an id parameter from one form (controller) to another.
Here I add an id to my model and it is passed on.

```
@Controller
public class PersonController 

 @RequestMapping(value = {"/addPerson"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePerson(Model model, //
                             @ModelAttribute("personForm") PersonForm personForm, RedirectAttributes attributes) {//, @ModelAttribute("person") Person newPerson) {

        String firstName = personForm.getFirstName();
        String lastName = personForm.getLastName();
        double money = personForm.getMoney();

        if (firstName != null && firstName.length() > 0
                && lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0) {
            Person newPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName, money);
            personService.save(newPerson);
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("id", newPerson.getId());//

            return "redirect:/addKonto";
        }

        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return "addPerson";
    }
```

I am passing data to another form and here the id is being passed correctly. size = 3

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/addKonto"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddKontoPage(Model model, @ModelAttribute("id") int id) {

        KontoForm kontoForm = new KontoForm();
        model.addAttribute("kontoForm", kontoForm);
        model.addAttribute("id", id);

        return "addKonto";
    }
```

when I try to pass my model further, the id parameter is lost. size = 2

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/addKonto"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveKonto(Model model,
                            @ModelAttribute("kontoForm") KontoForm kontoForm) {

        String kontoName = kontoForm.getKontoName();
        double moneyInKonto = kontoForm.getMoneyInKonto();
         model.getAttribute("id"); //    hier is null

        if (kontoName != null && kontoName.length() > 0) {
            Konto newKonto = new Konto(kontoName, moneyInKonto);

            kontoService.save(newKonto);

            return "redirect:/personList";
        }
```

how to get the id parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In your `savePerson` method you're adding a `attributes.addFlashAttribute()` instead of a `model.addAttribute()` like you are in your `showAddKontoPage` method.

Meaning, that for the attribute to be passed on from controller to controller via redirects, you need to add that attribute via the `model.addAttribute()` method.

You can add a new attribute to your Controller methods to accept the user id attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/addKonto"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddKontoPage(Model model,
                               @RequestParam(required = false) String id)
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/addKonto"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveKonto(Model model,
                        @ModelAttribute("kontoForm") KontoForm kontoForm,
                        @RequestParam(required = false) String id)
```

[Flash Messages](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-flash-attributes) are used to display a message to the end user via tags.

On a side note:

Spring has infrastructure to [Validate your Forms](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/).  It will be much better to use that infrastructure in the future, when you're ready for it of course.

Comment: if i add this  model.addAttribute("id", newPerson.getId());  to savePerson,  then showAddPersonPage doesn't accept id.

the problem is that in saveKonto the model has only kontoForm and no user id.

Comment: size = 3 means that the model has a kontoForm, validator and id

Comment: If your forms don't have user id in them, then you either need to pass the value as a parameter, via the controller method, or you'll need to add the user's id to your form.  I would recommend passing the user id via a method attribute.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to pass the parameter attribute to your controller methods.

Comment: then  id is null